# What's the name of jQuery functions that don't accept functions as parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

This a theoretical question:

Is there a generic name to refer to all those jQuery functions that don't accept functions as a parameter?
Such the index(), children(), height() ...

**UPDATE:**
If i know the name then I could make a question like this: "Can I pass a function to a "named" function?"

To give a little more detail, I have tried to pass a function as a parameter to jQuery's `.index()` method but it does not work:

```
 textbox.closest('tr').index(function(){var index = $(this);});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, ... why?

Comment: Parameterless.  Not that most of your examples are.  They just *can* be.

Comment: @roXon Because then I can make the following question: Can I pass a function to a "name" function?

Comment: The question is two-fold: Technically (syntactically) speaking you can pass a function object to any function as a parameter. But on semantics level some jQuery methods will throw an error because the type of parameter doesn't match the expected parameter

Answer (score 1):

All jQuery functions that take parameters can take functions. In JavaScript, functions are objects, and neither jQuery or vanilla JavaScript are type-safe. In other words, as long as the function accepts parameters, it will accept a function as one of its arguments.

Ergo, methods that do not accept any parameters are the only methods that will not accept functions.

**EDIT:**

If you want to get technical, then even methods that do not accept any parameters will still accept a function as an argument. Just as JavaScript isn't type-safe, it also doesn't actually enforce any rules regarding the function's signature, i.e. it doesn't check that the number of arguments entered matches the number of arguments defined. This is why you get a "null reference" error (if unhandled) instead of a "no function [function name] takes the arguments [arguments list]". This is also why you can pass an unlimited number of arguments to a function, even if it only takes one, two, or none.

**UPDATE:**

With regards to my solution to your original question, I would like to clarify by adding that jQuery is a solid language in that it often will simply return null when it is passed invalid arguments (but it will not error out when being passed an incorrect number of arguments). JavaScript is the same in many situations, but, as I implied and common sense would dictate, it would be nonsensical to pass too many or too few arguments to a method, regardless of legality.

With regards to your updates and your comments,  I think that you're misunderstanding the fundamental use of jQuery's `.index()` method. When used properly, this method is called on a collection of elements and has a selector (or an element to match) as a parameter, and returns the index of the first occurrence of an element that satisfies the given selector, or matches the given element.

**Update:**

From your updated example, I can see that I was correct in thinking that you are misunderstanding the use of the `.index()` function a little bit. The function takes either a selector or an element, but you passed a function that doesn't return either. Here is what you would need (using your existing syntax):

```
textbox.closest('tr').index(function(){ return $(this);});
```

OR (more simply):

```
textbox.closest('tr').index($(this));
```

To add a bit more detail (and, perhaps, better answer your initial question), you could also do something like this:

```
function getOnlyParagraphElements() {
    return this.tagName === "p";
}

var collection = $("body").find("*");
var firstParaIndex = collection.index(getOnlyParagraphElements);
```

This was only an example (and yes, I know that I could just use jQuery to get paragraphs), but the concept is the same - this is how you make your own selector.

Also note that in your examples, you are always checking against a one-item collection, meaning you will only get either the value `0` or the value `-1` (if the element doesn't match the selector/passed in element). If your goal is to get the index of the element that you are calling the method on relative to its siblings, then you need only call the method without supplying any parameters.

Comment: I've triyed to pass a paramterer to index function and does not work: textbox.closest('tr').index(function () { alert('hello'); });

Comment: Why would you think that would work? The jQuery `.index()` method takes a selector (or selector function) or an element as a parameter. You can pass that kind of function if you want, but it won't do anything because it's the wrong type of function.

Comment: Tell me explicitly what you are trying to do. Are you trying to get the index of an element and then call a callback function?

Comment: This answer is technically correct but not very meaningful. Sure, you "can" do `.index(function() {})` in that JavaScript doesn't throw a type error of some sort. But jQuery certainly does not accept a function here, and the behaviour is not defined. Just because it's legal JavaScript doesn't mean jQuery accepts it.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel More or less. I want to get the index element inside the function itself. But in fact, I don't need it it's just whether is it possible.

Comment: @pimvdb - I'm sorry that my answer was not very meaningful to you. I did do my best to describe the answer to his initial question - the Update that you now see is something that I added, as I thought that it might prompt some more helpful responses for senyortoni. I am about to update my response to accomodate the change to the post, which will hopefully help to give the solution more meaning to you, as well.

Comment: No worries :) I just think the OP meant something different (i.e. jQuery specific functions that accept functions in the semantical way).

Comment: @pimvdb - perhaps :) - I was more attempting to explain why there is no such thing as a JS function that will not accept other functions as arguments

Comment: @senyortoni - can you please update the example that I added to your post with a pseudo version of exactly what you would like to see if it is possible to do, or does my update answer your question?